# Change lock screen slide show images

Tags: windows-8.1, screensaver

Windows 8.1

A long time ago I set up a "screen saver" for the Windows lock screen. It displays a slideshow of images from a folder I chose.

I can't find the settings for this.

When I go into Screen saver settings, it says "(None)" under "Screen saver"? Which is right. I don't have a screen saver.

I can't find the settings that allow me to pic the folder from which the images are played, or any other settings related to this.

Where can I modify this kind of screen saver?

Edit:
Here's the screen saver dialog box.
[image]

ALSO, I can change the screen saver images by moving them into and out of the folder I previously designated. But that's just a workaround. That folder was not supposed to be a "screen saver images" folder. I should be able to change the target folder.

Comment: Is this a personal or work machine? or, at the bottom of the box where you go to change the screensaver settings, does it say '*One or more of the settings on this page has been disabled by the system administrator*'?

Comment: It's effectively a personal computer, completely under my control, purchased at Best Buy. I don't see that message. I've attached a screen shot of the Screen Saver Settings to my question.

Comment: That drop-down looks enabled.  Does it give any options when you click it?

Comment: @mcalex Yes! It lists the following screen savers: 3D Text, Bubbles, Mystify, Photos, and Ribbons. But, again, "(None)" is selected. And i just realized that what I'm really asking about is more like "lock screen slide show" rather than "screen saver slide show". These images appear when Windows is locked.

Comment: What happens when you select the 'Photos' screensaver?  Lock screen slide show sounds like screensaver slide show to me.

Comment: @mcalex It shows image previews from some default image folder and all the settings are default settings for the screen saver. I don't think the setting I'm looking for is actually in this window. It relates to the lock screen.

Comment: Settings -> Personalisation -> Lock Screen -> Background -> Slideshow

Answer (score 1):

Did not find such settings in my Win 8.1 as well.
After some research I found that my user's profile is broken: Start->Search type "Lock screen settings" gave me an error that Windows cannot access to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel...
After I copied the same folder from another profile, the error gone and I was able to get the settings you have asked about: http://prntscr.com/iiupnt